# Bringing interface up without a cable (but bridged VMs)

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, ethernet

I've set up a bridged network vm (i.e. virtual network hub, vm:192.168.1.2, host real network card: 192.168.1.1)

There's no network cable. As I do not care for one on this host->vm setup.

The vm sets up the network just fine.

On the host, `ifup enp3s0` and `ip link set enp3s0 up` and `networkctl up enp3s0` all exit with status code `0` but none do bring the interface up (nor generate any log messages anywhere i can see). As soon as I plug in a cable to the network I do not care about, even if just a dummy load for the level 3, everything starts up and works fine.

What is the correct way to actually bring the interface up onto the virtual HUB, without caring for a irrelevant physical cable?

(Some other answers to this problem mention wicd/network-manager causing problems. I do not have them on my system.)